# Download a svg with php

Tags: php, svg, download

I would like to create a php download for a svg. Rn i'm creating a segment which is a svg and now I want to put that segment in a download but don't know how.

There is the download part (download.php) and its loading the code from index.php

```
$file =  include('index.php');

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="segment.svg"');
header('Content-Type: image/svg');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($file));
header('Connection: close');

echo $file;
exit();
```

There is the index.php

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form action="index.php" method="get">
        <label for="segments">Segmente</label><br/>
        <input type="number" id="segments" name="segment">
        <input type="submit" value="Absenden" name="submit">
    </form>
<?php

$getSegment = $_GET['segment'];

// I deleted some code here

            <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg">
                <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++): ?>
                    <?php
                    $start_angle = $segment_arc * $i;
                    $end_angle = $segment_arc * ($i + 1);
                    ?>
                    <path fill="#red" stroke-width="0" d="<?php echo $generate_arc($start_angle, $end_angle) ?>" />
                <?php endfor ?>
            </svg>
        </div>
    <div class="container">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='download.php'">Download</button>
    </div>
</body>
        <?php
    }
    echo segment_circle($getSegment);
} else if (!isset($getSegment) || empty($getSegment)) {
    echo 'Bitte trag eine Segmentanzahl ein!';
}
```

There is a picture how it looks in the frontend
[image]

Comment: As the SVG structure itself is already in the HTML, I would use some JavaScript to extract it. This could be done by putting the SVG code inside a `<div id="svg-code">...</div>` so that you can easily extract it with `document.getElementById('svg-code').innerHTML`. Then [you can return it with this JS technique](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server). But if you do want it in PHP, then you have to pass the `segment` value to `download.php?segment=...`. Don't include `index.php` in `download.php` !

Comment: And how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my JavaScript solution without PHP code, which I explained quickly in the comment on your question.

### Why doing it in JS ?

**Advantages of the JS solution**

- No HTTP call so no processing on the server. This will save CPU and be much quicker for the end-user.
- Your page could include multiple SVG images and you don't need to handle this case on the server side. My JS solution handles multiple SVG images and download buttons.
- By the way, the SVG itself could be generated directly with JS instead of doing it with PHP.

**Disadvantage of the JS solution**

- If the browser hasn't got JS enabled then it will not work. But it's probably quite rare.

You could always falldown to the PHP solution. We'll let you do that yourself. In any case we haven't got your PHP code. I also don't understand your PHP loop `for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++):` which means that you only do it once, so the loop isn't necessary.

### How the JS solution works

1. You add some HTML markup around your SVG image and download button. This will seperate them if you have several ones in your page. I also added a `data-filename` attribute so that you can set different filenames easily. If the attribute isn't set then it falls down to a default value set in a constant.
2. The JavaScript code will add a *click* event handler on the download button. When this one will be triggered by a click it will do the following:

   1. Create a `<a>` element.
   2. Put the SVG code in the `href` attribute.
   3. Set the `download` attribute to have a nice filename.
   4. Make this `<a>` invisible and add it to the DOM.
   5. Simulate a *click* event on it to initiate the download.
   6. Remove the `<a>` element from the DOM as we don't need it anymore.

### The code and working demo

I created a Codepen.io here: [Download a SVG with JS](https://codepen.io/patacra/pen/XWgqwRv)

Here's the copy-pasted solution for reading.

**NOTICE: it doesn't work with Stackoverflow snippets on latest versions of *Chrome*, *Edge* (perhaps *Safari*) as *download* is disabled in iframes for security reasons**.

But it will work on your website as it is not embedded in an `<iframe>`.

```js
// An SVG file has an XML header which you don't use if the SVG is in the HTML document.
// As we want to generate a file, we'll add it before the <svg> tag to be compliant.
const SVG_XML_HEADER = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>';

// The default SVG filename in case the data-filename attribute isn't set.
const DEFAULT_SVG_FILENAME = 'cake.svg';

// Get all the SVG containers of the page.
let svg_containers = document.querySelectorAll('.svg-container');

// For each SVG container, we'll bind the click event to the button to download the SVG.
svg_containers.forEach(function (svg_container, i) {
  let svg_image = svg_container.querySelector('.svg-image');
  // Let's get an optional filename from the data-filename attribute.
  let svg_filename = svg_image.getAttribute('data-filename') || DEFAULT_SVG_FILENAME;
  // The SVG code is the XML header and the trimmed inner HTML of the <div class="svg-image">.
  let svg_code = SVG_XML_HEADER + "\n" + svg_image.innerHTML.trim();
    
  // Now we want to bind the click event to the button so that it can download the SVG code above.
  // First let's get the <button>.
  let download_button = svg_container.querySelector('button');
  // Add the "click" handler on it.
  download_button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    // To do the "download" we need to do create a <a> element and click on it:
    // Create the <a> element.
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    // Set it's href to have the SVG content directly in the URL.
    a.setAttribute('href', 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(svg_code));
    // Set the filename for the "save as" dialog box.
    a.setAttribute('download', svg_filename);
    // Don't display this link in the HTML page.
    a.style.display = 'none';
    // Put it in the HTML page so that we can click on it.
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    // This click will generate the download.
    a.click();
    // Remove the created link from the HTML page.
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.svg-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">

  <div class="svg-container">
    <div class="svg-image" data-filename="charkle_cake.svg">
      <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg">
        <path d="M100,100 h-90 a90,90 0 1,0 90,-90 z"
              fill="gray" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
  </div>

  <div class="svg-container">
    <div class="svg-image" data-filename="strawberry_cake.svg">
      <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg">
        <path d="M100,100 h-90 a90,90 0 1,0 90,-90 z"
              fill="#fee" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"
              transform="rotate(225, 100, 100)" />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
  </div>

  <div class="svg-container">
    <div class="svg-image">
      <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg">
        <path d="M100,100 h-90 a90,90 0 1,0 90,-90 z"
              fill="#efe" stroke="green" stroke-width="2"
              transform="rotate(135, 100, 100)" />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it helps. But since no answer was helpful, I'll just give it a try.
First, you can write the SVG code in a variable (e.g. $svg_content).
Then execute the following php-code:

```
file_put_contents("segment.svg", $svg_content);
```

Then you only need to create the link in the HTML code.

```
<a href="path/ISBN.svg" download>Download</a>.
```

Of course, only if the file has also been generated. I hope it helps, otherwise just disregard it!